# In terms of performance which one is better Dynamic Layout or XML Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am dynamically creating views as show below

```
 public class DynamicLayoutActivity extends Activity 
{
        private LinearLayout linear_layout,linear_main;
    private Button b1,b2,b3;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_layout_params,button_parameters; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        linear_main = new LinearLayout(this);

        linear_layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linear_layout_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linear_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linear_layout.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);
        linear_layout.setLayoutParams(linear_layout_params);
        linear_layout.setId(3);

  //      button_parameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        b1=new Button(this);
        b1.setText("Button1");
        b1.setId(31);
        b1.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);
//        b1.setLayoutParams(button_parameters);

        b2=new Button(this);
        b2.setText("Button1");
        b2.setId(32);
        b2.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);
//        b2.setLayoutParams(button_parameters);

        b3=new Button(this);
        b3.setText("Button1");
        b3.setId(33);
        b3.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.CENTER);
//        b3.setLayoutParams(button_parameters);

        linear_layout.addView(b1);
        linear_layout.addView(b2);
        linear_layout.addView(b3);

        linear_main.addView(linear_layout);

        setContentView(linear_main);
    }
}
```

Similarly,  I am doing the same by declaring everthing in an xml file as show below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Suppose assume i have 100 buttons in the Linear Layout mentioned above then which is the best way to do and which has the best performance related to memory occupied and execution time**

If you support a scenario, then please explain me your views why that scenario is best. Such that i can understand the use of **Infalting the xml** and **Creating Views Dynamically**

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your question

If you define Layout & controls in xml then you inflate them into code which i think will be bit slower than instantiating views manually.But i dont think we can make out the difference.

- Also you have following advantages if you use xml based layouts.

**1** they allows us to support various Screen Resolutions and Orientation (You need to place main.xml file for each profile in respective folder like ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi)

**2** You can easily alter your layouts without touching java code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you explain me why inflating Layout & controls from xml will be bit slower than instantiating views manually. I am asking this becoz i am in a dilemma that  instantiating views will take more time than inflating an xml file :(

Comment: Because when you inflate xml there must be some algorithm which parses or traverse through the xml to find element you requested.

Comment: Ya ur right It uses XMLPullParser to parse the layout xml files

Comment: yeah that may be causing microseconds delay